# Upgrade Magento 2.3 EE to Magento 2.4.3 error

Tags: magento2

I have followed below steps

switch store to maintenance mode :

```
bin/magento maintenance:enable
```

Run command :

```
composer require magento/product-enterprise-edition=2.4.3 --no-update
```

Apply updates :

```
composer update
```

and getting this error

problem 1

```
- magento/magento-cloud-metapackage 2.3.6 requires magento/product-enterprise-edition >=2.3.6 <2.3.7 -> satisfiable by magento/product-enterprise-edition[2.3.6-p1, 2.3.6] but these conflict with your requirements or minimum-stability.
- magento/magento-cloud-metapackage 2.3.6 requires magento/product-enterprise-edition >=2.3.6 <2.3.7 -> satisfiable by magento/product-enterprise-edition[2.3.6-p1, 2.3.6] but these conflict with your requirements or minimum-stability.
- Installation request for magento/magento-cloud-metapackage >=2.3.6 <2.3.7 -> satisfiable by magento/magento-cloud-metapackage[2.3.6].
```

how to fix it ?

Comment: any thoughts on this ?

Comment: any thoughts on this ?

Comment: any thoughts on this ?

Comment: Hey @magedev, Did you find the solution?

Answer (score 1):

You need to make manual changes to your composer.json file, as explained in [the DevDocs](https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.4/comp-mgr/cli/cli-upgrade.html#manage-packages):

> 2. Add or remove specific packages based on your needs. For example, if you are upgrading from Magento Open Source to Adobe Commerce,
>    remove the Magento Open Source package.
>
>    `$ composer remove magento/product-community-edition --no-update`

In your case, you probably need to do one of two things:

1. If you are not working in an Adobe Commerce Cloud environment, remove magento/magento-cloud-metapackage. This is [only used on the cloud](https://devdocs.magento.com/cloud/composer-packages/patch-notes.html) and you don't need it.
2. If you are working in an Adobe Commerce Cloud environment, update your composer.json entry to this: `"magento/magento-cloud-metapackage": "2.4.3"` The error message is your friend here, telling you that your cloud metapackage version and desired Magento version are incompatible.

After you resolve this, you may have other composer adjustments to make. You'll have to work through the error messages one at a time and resolve them in a similar manner. Unfortunately, it's just one of those unavoidable and tedious processes that is often par for the course when upgrading Magento.

Comment: I have Updated magento-cloud-metapackage dependency  "magento/magento-cloud-metapackage": "2.4.3" in require section of composer.json

Comment: Did that get you through this error, or is it still throwing?

Comment: Its been solved

Comment: Okay, great. I've edited my answer to align with what you did. Can you mark it as accepted to help others in the community who come looking?

Comment: Sure can you please edit further as i am upgrading magento EE 2.3 to EE 2.4
magento/product-enterprise-edition

Comment: If you're referring to the "magento/product-community-edition," that's a direct quote of Magento's DevDocs. If you're referring to something else, let me know and I'll be happy to help if I can.